# ASP MVC 5 EF - Saving application settings -

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to save my application settings like wordpress saves its app settings in wp_options table.

`wp_options` table schema is as follows:

```
option_id option_name option_value     autoload
-------------------------------------------------
1         siteurl     'mywebsite.com'  yes

2         blogname    'myblog'         yes
```

If I save like this then I wont be able to directly access values like `object['siteurl']`. Do I need to make custom mappings?

I am using Entity Framework btw.

Comment: Yes, for that you've to do custom mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a mapping sample just to give you an idea.

```
public class Option
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsAutoload { get; set; }
}
```

Create a dictionary..

```
Dictionary<string, Option> WP_Options = new Dictionary<string, Option>();

List<Option> options = context.Wp_Options.Select(r => new Option() 
{ 
    Id = r.option_id, 
    Name = r.option_name, 
    Value = r.option_value, 
    IsAutoload = r.option_autoload == "yes" 
}; // store records into a list

foreach(Option option in options)
{
    WP_Options.Add(option.Name, option); // Store to dictionary
}
```

You can now access your options like:

```
Option siteUrl = WP_Options["siteurl"];
var val = siteUrl.Value;
bool autoload = siteUrl.IsAutoload;
```

If you are familiar with singleton classes then I'd suggest creating one that exposes the dictionary WP_Options. With this, you can access the same instance of the WP_Options across your application.

You'd just have to handle the option saving to the database.

Here's a little sample:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Option> entry in WP_Options)
{
    if(context.Wp_Options.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == entry.Value) != null)
    {
        // Entry exists do an update logic
    }
    else
    {
        // Entry does not exist do an insert logic
    }
}

// save data context
```

Comment: A singleton class would serve as a system wide cache, thanks :)